# Which ML algorithm would be appropriate for clustering a combination of categorical and numerical dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wish to cluster a DataFrame with a dimension of (120000 x 4).

It consists of two string-based "label" columns (str1 and str2), and two numerical columns which looks like the following:

```
    Str1 Str2  Energy    intensity  
0   713  599  7678.159  5367.276014  
1   715  598  7678.182  6576.100453  
2   714  597  7678.183  5675.788001  
3   684  587  7678.493  3040.650157  
4   693  588  7678.585  5585.908164  
5   695  586  7678.615  3184.001905  
6   684  584  7678.674  4896.774505  
7   799  509  7693.645  4907.484401  
8   798  508  7693.754  4075.800912  
9   797  507  7693.781  4407.800702  
10  796  506  7694.043  3138.073328  
11  794  505  7694.049  3653.699936  
12  795  504  7694.077  3875.120022  
13  675  277  7694.948  3081.797654  
14  709  221  7698.216  3587.704908  
15  708  220  7698.252  4070.050144   
...........
```

What would be the best ML algorithm to cluster/categorize this data?

I have tried plotting individual energy&intensity components belonging to one specific category Str1== "713" etc, which didn't give me much information. I am in need of somewhat more compact clustering, if possible.

Comment: [K-Modes](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/kmodes-clustering-algorithm-for-categorical-data/), or [K-Prototypes](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-k-prototype-as-clustering-algorithm-for-mixed-data-type-categorical-and-numerical-fe7c50538ebb)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do categorical encoding or one-hot encoding to Str1 and Str2 (categorical encoding is suitable for the class with magnitude relation, while one-hot encoding is more widely used), these will convert the string into numerical data, can you can just simply use any regression model.